What does kind of pc-xxxx labels on RAM means?
I start work with testing PCs and there is a lot RAMs with only mark kind of pc800 and another. Is there a table with all similar marks and their explanation? (sorry for my bad english)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have a look at the table on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAM

My problem, so to speak, is that all RAMs are mostly signed only by PC xxx (the label is on the RAM itself). As I understood, this description is called a RAM module. And the question is whether there is a table, for example, with one column pc xxx and others with a description of the characteristics and model of the motherboard or a resource where it is detailed (about the description of the pc)?

if its DDR2 look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAM#Module_specifications  for DDR3: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#Modules for DDR4: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_DDR4_module and for DDR5: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR5_SDRAM (They don't have a nice table for them, because I believe the standards docs are not public).

Usually, the label on memory modules will include the name of the manufacturer, model number, serial/lot number, size, and speed class. If some of this information is missing, you might look at the markings of individual memory chips for further identification.
If the only visible text on a memory module is PC800 and there is nothing else, it might mean one of two things:

They might be factory-default memory modules for pre-built systems, with custom "simple" labelling ordered by the computer manufacturer to minimize mistakes in the computer assembly line.

Or they might be counterfeit memory modules, as a genuine memory module manufacturer usually wants their brand name prominently displayed to make themselves recognizable to the customers. A counterfeiter might make their product look like a well-known memory manufacturer's products, but then they might be sued for trademark violation. Another alternative would be to make the counterfeit products look as generic as possible.


The PC usually refers to the standard memory speed classification, which is maintained by JEDEC for all SDRAM memory types. However, sometimes memory module manufacturers may add their own model number schemes that may seem confusingly similar to the JEDEC classification names.
In particular, PC800 seems to be ambiguous: it might refer to a particular speed grade of RDRAM memory, which was a competitor of SDRAMs in the 1990s. Or it might be plain old DDR2 SDRAM, manufactured by Crucial.
Wikipedia has separate pages for DDR SDRAM, DDR2 SDRAM, DDR3 SDRAM, DDR4 SDRAM, the newest DDR5 SDRAM and the previously-mentioned RDRAM, each with a table of corresponding speed classifications.
All DIMM-style memory modules should contain a SPD (Serial Presence Detect) chip, which contains all the important specifications of the memory module in a machine-readable form. Memory testers and hardware identification utility prograns can often decode this information and show it. If the information in the SPD does not at all match with the memory module label, the memory module is most likely counterfeit.

telcoM  thank you for answer
